# How can I get Komodo Edit 7 to autocomplete C?

Tags: c, autocomplete, komodoedit, code-intelligence

I am using Komodo Edit 7.1 to write C code, but it won't autocomplete function names or macros that are declared in included header files, even if they're in the same directory, even if I have them open. What is required to get Komodo Edit to incorporate C header files into its Code Intelligence?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python to create a lexer using the following resources:

- [Komodo Code Intelligence Repository](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/src/codeintel)
- [Komodo File Locations](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations)
- [Komodo Extension Tutorial](http://trentm.com/2007/09/an-intro-to-komodo-extensions.html)
- [R Language Autocomplete Project](http://community.activestate.com/forum/code-intelligence-putting-it-all-together)
- [Leo Language Autocomplete Project](http://leo.zwiki.org/Autocompletion)